# ASP.NET Core MVC : AutoMapper Map ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I would like to use AutoMapper to map my model to my view model to display in the view and then later-on save back to the database.

I am able successfully map model to view model fields except for the `ICollection` data. I reviewed and I do get the ICollection when populating the model

My model for example:

```
public class CarDetails 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Make{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CarId")]
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public int? CarFlag { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public ICollection<CarDetails> CarDetails { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }   
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

My view model for example:

```
public class CarDetailsVM
{
    public string Make{ get; set; }
    public int? CarFlag { get; set; }
}

public class CarVM
{
    public ICollection<CarDetailsVM> CarDetailsVM{ get; set; }        
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

My mapping profile:

```
   CreateMap<Car, CarVM>().ReverseMap();
   CreateMap<CarDetails, CarDetailsVM>().ReverseMap();
```

In my controller - I get the information:

```
  Car model = repo.GetData(1);

  var vm = _mapper.Map<CarVM>(model);
```

When I review vm object, I see all fields except for the `CarDetailsVM` collection values. I check the model and I see it is retrieving the data from `repo.GetData(1)`

Any suggestions on how to map `ICollection` model to VM `ICollection`?

And on submit I would do: would that be correct way?

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Car(CarVM viewModel)
{
    var carObject  = repo.GetData(1);
    var mappedCar = _mapper.Map<CarVM, Car>(viewModel, carObject);
    ....//then I would pass mappedCar to repo to save to DB
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the name of the Collection property differs in both models, you need to specifiy them. For example,

```
CreateMap<Car, CarVM>().ForMember(dest => dest.CarDetailsVM, 
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CarDetails))
                .ReverseMap();
```

This would ensure the collection is mapped when using the Map() method.

Alternatively, You can could specify PostFix to be removed from the Source when finding the matching property in Destination type using the `RecognizePostfixes` method.

```
public CarProfile()
{
  RecognizePostfixes("VM");
  CreateMap<Car, CarVM>().ReverseMap();
  CreateMap<CarDetails, CarDetailsVM>().ReverseMap();
}
```

Read more on the Postfix/Prefix configuration in [Automapper documentation](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#recognizing-pre-postfixes)